# Ruby on rails: unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i have a problem like the subject in the controller. I've got error of expecting end of function. But as you can see I've got every end of the function. I'm a beginner in RoR.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_catalogs = @user.catalogs
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@user.locations) do |location, marker|
    marker.lat location.latitude
    marker.lng location.longitude
    marker.infowindow location.address
  end

  def index
       @users = User.where.not("id = ?",current_user.id).order("created_at DESC")
       @conversations = Conversation.involving(current_user).order("created_at DESC")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed `end` in `show` method. Try this:

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_catalogs = @user.catalogs
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@user.locations) do |location, marker|
      marker.lat location.latitude
      marker.lng location.longitude
      marker.infowindow location.address
    end
  end
```

Comment: Aaaah that was quicker, plus one for your speed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_catalogs = @user.catalogs
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@user.locations) do |location, marker|
    marker.lat location.latitude
    marker.lng location.longitude
    marker.infowindow location.address
    end <<<<< here!
  end
```

Comment: Thank you very very much :)

Comment: @JakubOstrowski You are wellcome, please don't forget to accept only one answer with the (✓)